# How to make srtm data part of geoserver

Tags: geoserver, cesiumjs

I have downloaded srtm data, which has the below structure:
srtm_51_08
    srtm_51_08.hdr
    srtm_51_08.tfw
    srtm_51_08.tif

Now inside geoserver folder where do i copy-paste this "srtm_51_08" folder ?
I am using geoserver version 2.11.1.
When i pasted it inside \data_dir\workspaces\ folder, the geoserver started up with the warning:

" WARN [org.geoserver] - Ignoring workspace directory workspaces/srtm_51_08 "

How do i include it, so that it is not ignored by geoserver, as i want to use it in my app as below:

```
var globe = new Cesium.Globe(Cesium.Ellipsoid.WGS84);
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.GeoserverTerrainProvider({      
url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/ows?service=wms&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities",
layerName: "srtm_51_08",      
});    
globe.terrainProvider = terrainProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try looking in the [manual](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/index.html)? May be the section on [World Images](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/worldimage.html) or preferably convert it to a geotiff and use [GeoTiffs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/geotiff.html)?